# How to call JAX-WS method from URL

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl, jax-ws

I have a local web service and I can call its methods using a JAVA client.

Is it possible to access its methods using a URL ?
I can access the wsdl XML using this URL:

http://localhost:9999/ws/hello?wsdl

And I would like to call a method like such:

http://localhost:9999/ws/hello/getHelloWorldAsString?name=test

But I am receiving errors "Localhost did not send any data".

Is there a way to do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I was aware Jax-ws uses POST to receive calls. You will have to build an XML request to POST to your URL. Something like this:

```
POST /ws/hello HTTP/1.1
SOAPAction: ""
Accept: text/xml, multipart/related, text/html, image/gif, image/jpeg, *; q=.2,   */*; q=.2
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
User-Agent: Java/1.6.0_13
Host: localhost:9999
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 224

<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <S:Body>
        <ns2:getHelloWorldAsString xmlns:ns2="http://ws.mkyong.com/">
            <arg0>test</arg0>
        </ns2:getHelloWorldAsString>
    </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use java.net.Url and HttpURLConnection or HTTPSURLConnection

look a sample

```
    URL url = new URL("http://yourwebservices.soap.wsdl");
    HttpURLConnection connectionWS = (HttpURLConnection) ur.openConnection();
    //not forget this
    connectionWS.setDoOutput(true);
    connectionWS.setDoInput(true);
    connectionWS.setRequestMethod("POST");
    connectionMinervaWS.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "text/xml; charset=utf-8");

   StringBuilder envelopeSoapRequest = new StringBuilder()
   //make the xml request

   //now you send to service
   OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter( connectionWS.getOutputStream() );
   osw.write( envelopeSoapRequest.toString() );
   osw.flush();

   //now you can take response
   BufferedReader wsReader = null;
   StringBuilder envelopeSoapResponse = new StringBuilder();
   wsReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( 
   connectionWS.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8 ));
   String line = wsReader.readLine();

   while (line != null) {
      envelopeSoapResponse.append( line );
      line = wsReader.readLine();
   }
```